# How to use struct with stack?

Tags: c++, stl

Normally when we use stack we do this....

```
stack<int>st;
st.push(1);
st.push(2);
st.push(3);

cout<<st.top<<"\n"
```

But my question is how to push and access data when we use struct instead of int/char type variable? For example...

```
struct st
{
  int index, value;
};
int main()
{
  stack<st>STACK;
  /*
     code
  */

}
```

Now, here how can I push element in stack and access them?

Comment: `stack.emplace(10, 20);`, `auto [index, value] = stack.top();`.

Comment: @Evg I believe that requires C++20.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, without a constructor, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push to `std::stack` by using [Aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), or adding a constructor to your structure or `std::stack::emplace`.

By using constructor:

```
struct st
{
  st(int _index, int _value) : index(_index), value(_value) {}
  int index, value;
};

std::stack<st> s;
s.push(st(10, 20));
```

By using Aggregate initialization:

```
std::stack<int> s;
s.push({10, 20});
```

To access the element simply call `std::stack::top()`.

```
st top = s.top();
```

or by using C++17 [Structured binding declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding):

```
auto [index, value] = s.top();
```

Comment: Another way to push, perhaps obvious: `st x = {10, 20}; STACK.push(x);`.

Comment: `s.push(st(10, 20));` ~ `s.emplace(10, 20);`

Comment: It was such simple but never came to my mind. @therealcain thanks for your help .